# weather app: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, http

I am trying to build a weather app using node that takes
{

"cities": [
"toronto",
"mumbai",
"london"
]
}
as input and returns

```
{
  "weather": {
    "toronto": "24C",
    "mumbai": "34C",
    "london": "14C"
  }
}
```

this as output

```
app.post('/getWeather',(req,res)=>{
    const city = req.body.city;
    city.map(city=>{
    const url=`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}`;
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {

        // On return, check the json data fetched
        if (err) {
            res.render('index', { weather: null, error: 'Error, please try again' });
        } else {
            let weather = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(weather);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question does not have all of the code, I cannot give a definite answer, but I assume that the code either tries to sent response for the each city separately and/or does not wait for all the API calls to finish.

To fix the issue, async/await needs to be used (since the response depends on several API calls), and response must be sent after its completely assembled.

An example based on the given code:

```js
app.post("/getWeather", async (req, res) => {
  const cities = req.body.cities;
  const reqs = cities.map((city) => {
    const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request(url, function (err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          let weather = JSON.parse(body);
          resolve(weather);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  const responses = await Promise.all(reqs);
  const result = {};
  for (const response of responses) {
    if (response.ok) {
      result[response.city] = response.temp;
    }
  }
  res.json(result);
});
```

Comment: the code doesn't want the api calls to finish and return the response at the end

Comment: @SomeshDebnath what do you mean? Elaborate please